# Sending array of Json objects to Web Method using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

What should the WebMethod's parameter be called below to get the json array sent from client? I used `name`, but it didn't work.

```
var employees = {
            "accounting": [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                  {
                      "firstName": "",  // First element
                      "lastName": "Doe",
                      "age": 23
                  },

                  {
                      "firstName": "Mary",  // Second Element
                      "lastName": "Smith",
                      "age": 32
                  }
            ], // End "accounting" array.                                  
            "sales": [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                              {
                                  "firstName": "Sally", // First Element
                                  "lastName": "Green",
                                  "age": 27
                              },

                              {
                                  "firstName": "Jim", // Second Element
                                  "lastName": "Galley",
                                  "age": 41
                              }
            ] // End "sales" Array.
        } // End Employees

var toServer = JSON.stringify(employees);
```

This is the jquery ajax to send it to Web Method.

```
$("#sendtoServer").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                url         : "Default.aspx/GetDetails",
                data        : '{name: "' + toServer + '" }',
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType    : "json",
                success     : OnSuccess,
                failure     : function (response) {
                    alert("Wrong");
                }
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                alert("Sent");
            }
        });
```

And this is the Web Method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDetails(string name)
{
     var x=name;
     return "";
}
```

Comment: If you tell the server that you are sending JSON, you actually have to send JSON. `'{name: "' + toServer + '" }'` is not JSON. Maybe do only `data: toServer` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewrite your data initialization:

```
var employees = {
                    accounting: [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                          {
                              firstName: "",  // First element
                              lastName: "Doe",
                              age: 23
                          },

                          {
                              firstName: "Mary",  // Second Element
                              lastName: "Smith",
                              age: 32
                          }
                    ], // End "accounting" array.                                  
                    sales: [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                                      {
                                          firstName: "Sally", // First Element
                                          lastName: "Green",
                                          age: 27
                                      },

                                      {
                                          firstName: "Jim", // Second Element
                                          lastName: "Galley",
                                          age: 41
                                      }
                    ] // End "sales" Array.
                } // End Employees



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetDetails",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ name: employees }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Wrong");
                    }
                });

                function OnSuccess(response) {
                    alert("Sent");
                }
```

use object parameter type on server side:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDetails(object name)
{
     var x=name;
     return "";
}
```

Edit:
The quotes removal is not needed as @Felix Kling pointed out.

Comment: Lovely. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Jude: Please note that there is no need to remove the quotation marks from the property names. The only important differences are `data: JSON.stringify({ name: employees })` and `GetDetails(object name)`. Although `data: JSON.stringify(employees)` would suffice as well, there is no need to add an additional level to the object structure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to simply change your web method to:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDetails(object name)
{
     var x=name;
     return "";
}
```